# $\frac{n!}{\frac{n}{2}!(n-\frac{n}{2})!} \in O(n^{34})$?

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity

$\frac{n!}{\frac{n}{2}!(n-\frac{n}{2})!} \in O(n^{34})$?

In Mathematica I have:

```
((x!) / ((x/2)!*(x-(x/2))! ) ) / (x^34) 

x -> inf
```

Mathematica return:

$lim_{x->infinity} \frac{x!}{((\frac{x}{2}! (x-\frac{x}{2})!) x^{34} )} = 0$

This is true?

Comment: This is a middle binomial coefficient and there are bounds on this on wikipedia page for binomial coefficients.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha approves :D https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((x!)+%2F+((x%2F2)!*(x-(x%2F2))!+)+)+%2F+(x%5E34)+,+x+-%3E+infty The answers here are still right. It appears to be a bug in Mathematica.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume $n$ is even (to avoid annoying considering about the factorial of a non-inter), you have
$$\binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}} = \frac{n!}{\frac{n}{2}!^2} \operatorname*{\sim}_{n\to\infty}
\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\frac{2^n}{\sqrt{n}}
$$
which you can obtain via [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) (applied to the three factorials).

In particular, this means $$\binom{n}{\frac{n}{2}} = \frac{n!}{\frac{n}{2}!^2} = 2^{n-o(1)}
$$
so **no**, this is not $O(n^{34})$. *(It grows faster than any fixed polynomial in $n$.)*

Comment: I think you missed something in your first \binom

Comment: @SK19 Thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Stirling's approximation says that for large $n$, $n!$ behaves like $(n/e)^n$. As a result ${2n \choose n}$ behaves like $(2n/e)^{2n}/(n/e)^{2n}=2^{2n}$ which is exponential and in particular superpolynomial.

Comment: In does not "behave like" this. You have a $o(1)$ in the exponent -- a multiplicative factor of $1/\sqrt{n}$ (which does not change the answer to the question, but makes a quite big difference mathematically: $\binom{2n}{n} = o(2^{2n})$)

Comment: @ClementC. I didn't say exactly what I meant by "behaves like". I am aware that a more precise asymptotic statement is ${2n \choose n}=\Theta(4^n/\sqrt{n})$, but the next order of Stirling's approximation is not at all necessary to answer this question.

Comment: I know -- sorry to nitpick here, but being precise is crucial when dealing with basic questions about asymptotic growth. *You* know the difference, but it's very easy to find students, or even graduate students, that do not differentiate between $O(2^n)$ and $2^{O(n)}$. Making sure the answer to basic questions is precise enough is crucial to prevent things from going haywire.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a direct argument for superpolynomial growth without using anything like Stirling. Your expression (in the case $n = 2k$ is even) is just

$$\frac{(2k)!}{(k!)^2} = \frac{2k \cdot (2k - 1) \cdot(2k - 2) \cdots (k + 1) }{k \cdot (k - 1) \cdot (k - 2) \cdots 1}$$

Match each term in the numerator with its corresponding term in the denominator. The term in the numerator is at least twice as large as the term in the denominator, so the $k$ terms now give us

$$\frac{(2k)!}{(k!)^2} \ge 2^k.$$